# $n k^n$ summation question

Tags: summation

How does one prove that

[image]

Can this be extended to higher powers such as:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify what $k$ is in your question?

Comment: k is any real constant, independent of n.

Comment: It's really hard to prove stuff like that. False statements are tricky that way.

Comment: Think about when $k$ is a big positive number.  The $n=1$ term is huge on the left and small on the right. Further terms are even more so, so the claimed equality is false.  Why do you believe it is true?  -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sides are trivially equal (and diverge) when $k = 1$. Otherwise, they are not equal.

Using the ratio test, we can see that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nk^n$ converges if $|k|<1$ and diverges if $|k| > 1$. Similarly, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nk^{-n}$ converges if $|k| > 1$ and diverges if $|k| < 1$. The two sides clearly cannot be equal if one side converges exactly at the times when the other diverges.

You can make a similar argument for the second equation.

Comment: Minor nitpick: there is equality when $k = 0$. Edit: I suppose its actually not defined for $k = 0$.